# Stereographic projection and arclength metric

Tags: real-analysis, projective-geometry

On $\mathbb{Z}\cup\left\{\pm\infty\right\}$ I would like to consider the metric $d$ which is defined by the arclength metric $d_{arc}$ on the inverse stereographic projection with projection Center $(0,1)$ of the semi-circle on the real-line (see the Picture).

That is, I would like to consider
$$
d(p,q):=d_{arc}(p',q'):=\text{arclength}(p',q').
$$

[image: stereographic projection]

My first problem is to find a formula for the inverse stereographic projection in order to identify the Points on the real line with their Points on the semi-circle.

Let $p\in\mathbb{R}$. Then the line through $(0,1)$ and $(p,0)$ should be
$$
f(x)=-\frac{x}{p}+1.
$$
The semi-circle should have parametrization
$$
g(x)=-\sqrt{1-x^2}+1.
$$
Hence, in order to determine the Point $p'$ on the semi-circle, I should solve
$$
-\frac{x}{p}+1=-\sqrt{1-x^2}+1,
$$
yielding
$$
x_1=-\frac{p}{\sqrt{p^2+1}},~~~x_2=\frac{p}{\sqrt{p^2+1}}.
$$
I think, only $x_2$ makes sense here. Putting $x_2$ in $f$ or $g$ yields $f(x_2)=g(x_2)=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{p^2+1}}+1$.

So the Point $p'$ on the semi-circle should be given by
$$
p'=\left(\frac{p}{\sqrt{p^2+1}},-\frac{1}{\sqrt{p^2+1}}+1
\right)
$$

Hence, the inverse stereographic projection $S^{-1}$ here should be given by
$$
S^{-1}(x)=\begin{cases}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}},-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}+1
\right), & x\in\mathbb{R}\\(1,1), & x=+\infty\\(-1,1), & x=-\infty\end{cases}
$$

Am I right?

My second Problem now is to define the arclength for Points on the semi-circle.

Comment: I guess you mean $\mathbb{R} \cup \{ \pm \infty \}$ and not $\mathbb{Z} \cup \{ \pm \infty \}$.

Comment: No, I mean $\mathbb{Z}\cup\left\{\pm\right\}$. But I thought it would make no difference if I determine the whole Thing for $\mathbb{R}\cup\left\{\pm\infty\right\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The length of the arc $p'q'$ is the angle  $\theta = \angle PAQ$ (in radians) which can be found by computing the dot product. More explicitly, we have

$$ \cos \theta = \frac{ \left< \vec{AP}, \vec{AQ} \right>}{\| \vec{AP} \| | \vec{AQ} \|} = \frac{ \left< (p,-1), (q,-1) \right>}{ \| (p,-1) \| \| (q, -1) \|} = \frac{pq + 1}{\sqrt{(p^2 + 1)(q^2 + 1)}} $$

and so

$$ d(p,q) = \arccos \left( \frac{pq + 1}{\sqrt{(p^2 + 1)(q^2 + 1)}} \right). $$

Comment: That means, in order to determine the metric, I do not have to determine the (inverse) stereographic projection first... :-)

Comment: @mathfemi: Yep :)

Comment: What, if for example $p\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ and $q=+\infty$? What is then $d(p,q)$?

Comment: @mathfemi: Then $d(p,q) = \arccos \left( \lim_{q \to +\infty} \frac{pq + 1}{\sqrt{(p^2 + 1)(q^2 + 1)}} \right) = \arccos \left( \frac{p}{\sqrt{p^2 + 1}} \right)$.

Comment: Or we use the formula for the inverse stereographic projection and compute the angle between $\vec{Ap}$ and $\vec{AQ'}$ with $Q'=(1,1)$ and $A=(0,1)$.

Comment: @mathfemi: That also works but you don't need the stereographic projection - you can use my approach with the dot product.

Comment: Your Approach is definitely more elegant! Thank you :D

Comment: When we restrict the arclength metric on $\mathbb{Z}\Cup\left\{\pm\infty\right\}$ am I right that $d(p,q)<\min\left\{d(p,p-1),d(p,p+1)\right\}$ implies that $p=q$?